# how to drag and drop a image using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I've tried this it select a element but does not move or drop a element:

```
browser.driver.actions()
// source location
.mouseMove(drg,{x:0,y:150})
.mouseDown()
.mouseMove(drg,{x:0,y:0})
// destination location
.mouseMove(drp,{x:55,y:0})
.mouseUp()
.perform(); 
 browser.driver.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: may be the same but this question isn't resolved yet : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280718/protractor-how-to-do-a-drag-and-drop-action

Comment: Are you sure the `drg` element is actually graggable?

Comment: yes i m sure ,,and i am also find the solution onbelow link but i dont know how to do it     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917772/protractor-drag-drop-function-working-with-mozilla-and-chrome-but-not-with-inte?rq=1

Comment: guys please help me out